# Using PHP to Extract Content From Tags

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Given an HTML file, how can PHP be used to extract strings from each, say, `<font>` tag within the document?

Comment: Have you read up on [DOM manipulation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) with PHP?

Comment: [Many exmaples already](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+extract+tag+contents&submit=search)

Comment: @Spudley, I'm working with HTML emails, so `<font>` tags are necessary...

Comment: name a mail client that supports html but not the inline css font ?

Comment: @Dagon Outlook, Free, Goo, T-Online... need i go on?

Comment: outlook supports css for font

Comment: @Dagon what magical version of Outlook are you using? The 2007/2010 version doesn't support inline css

Comment: @585connor it sure does; if you don't believe me how about this link or quite a few others: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/, i write a couple of email templates a week using in-line css for various email clients. while support sucks compared to web browsers, the css basics are covered - but of course tables for layout is still required

Comment: There is nothing bad with HTML 4 and font tags. Those are only deprecated, not removed. Also a good DOM Parser does not care about the concrete tagname, that's the job of a validator.

Answer (score 4):

There are many PHP libraries that can aid you in this case.

**SimpleXML**: https://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

**PHP's XML parser**: http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php

Simply use these libraries and denote the tag (in your example `font`) and you will be able to extract the string contents accordingly.

Comment: SimpleTest??? did you mean simplexml?

Answer (score 1):

As an example, you can use PHP's [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument) class to extract the contents, like this:

```
$html = '<font>Hello</font> <font>, World!</font>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML( $html);

foreach( $doc->getElementsByTagName( 'font') as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

This prints the inner values of the `<font>` tags, so it [will output](http://viper-7.com/vwSd4P):

```
Hello, World!
```

Answer (score -1):

using a dom parser..

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ is an example of one.

Comment: Yes... that was the first result I got too...

Comment: @val - **Pasting the first result you get from Google** is not putting any effort into answering the question.  This should have been a comment.

Comment: @Lix reading is an art. My first line is the answer. The second is an example

Comment: You just make my point stronger - 4 words is hardly an answer.  TBH I'm a little surprised that the system allowed you to post such a short answer. I was [under the impression](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130926/increase-minimum-word-count-with-links) that it was recently tweaked...

Comment: Sigh, 4 words what the user perfectly understands or a block of sentences where you give the whole explanation of everything what has nothing to do with it. I don't know what you would choose but I would go for the first one.

Comment: @VinceV., You should give a basic example in your answer.  If you don't wish to do this, then add snippets like this as a comment, rather than a full answer to the question.  I didn't downvote you, nor upvote you.  Also, I find it amusing that the other answer here has three votes with little more information than you posted.